# Can't use ethtool | bash: ethtool: command not found

Tags: linux, bash, debian

https://imgur.com/a/lM6H1v5
https://imgur.com/a/gnrydo4
I have Gigabit Ethernet on my phone and another PC(Windows), however on that one where I have Debian 12, it doesn't work. I have tried to install the ethtool package but I'm not able to use it :0. I can see the list of commands when I type man ethtool, however, that is all that I can receive from the console.

Comment: Not found => `$ sudo apt install --reinstall ethtool` ? --> `$ ethtool -h`

Comment: perhaps you need to `sudo ethtool`